# How to get the ActiveStorage attachment URL in a rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake-task, rails-activestorage

I have a rake task which stores images in `ActiveStorage`. In the same rake task I need the attachment URL of those images.

In a normal Rails context, I'd use `url_for(my_attachment)`. That helper is not available in a rake task though.

I tried to include the route helper:

```
task my_task: :environment do
  include MyApp::Application.routes.url_helpers

  attachment = my_model.image.attach(..)
  url_for(attachment)
end
```

Which results in:

```
*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `attachment_url' for main:Object
```

Is there any way to get the public URL of an attachment in a rake task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasted a lot of time looking for get a file URL working on a Module file, but here is the answer:

**If you need to create a link from outside of controller/view context (Background jobs, Cronjobs, etc.), you can access the rails_blob_path like this:**

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(user.avatar, only_path: true)
```

I founded this on this link [Redirect Mode :: Active Storage](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#redirect-mode)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, `.attach(..)` returns an array. The following does work:

```
task my_task: :environment do
  include MyApp::Application.routes.url_helpers

  attachment = my_model.image.attach(..).first

  Rails.configuration.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost'
  url_for(attachment)
end
```

The host in `default_url_options` needs to be set as well if it is not already set.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing my own custom controller for permalinks to images that I use in rake tasks. This seems hacky, but might be the intended behaviour, I'm not sure. This might save someone a bunch of time:

```
class ImageFilesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    mymodel = MyModel.find(params[:id])
    send_data(
      mymodel.name_of_attachment.blob.download,
      type: mymodel.name_of_attachment.blob.content_type,
      disposition: :inline
    )
  end
end
```